# ASP.Net Alert is disappearing after few seconds

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm displaying BootStrap alert in my MVC application. Here is an alert code snippet.

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible d-none" id="age-category-message" role="alert" aria-atomic="true">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

the alert shows only upon action and disappears after few seconds,
I want to display it for some more time, so how can I extend the default disposal time of the bootstrap alert?

Answer (score 0):

you can add div id with with your div class then simply add timeout function

```
<div class="row" id="myid">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible d-none" id="age-category-message" role="alert" aria-atomic="true">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

then add javascript function

```
function myFunction() {
  setTimeout(function(){ $("#myid").hide(); }, 5000);
}
```

this will display for 5 seconds